# How do I get Navigation Bar in UIView/Utility class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Actually I need to get the navigation bar in custom view class. I can get the navigaiton bar height in my view controller class. How do I get the naviagtion bar height in the UIView/Utiity common class? . I have only one view controller and added navigation controller in that class. I want to access that navigation bar height in any of the custom view.

```
    // works in view controller 
    var navigationBarHeight: CGFloat {
    return UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height +
        (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0.0)
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that You added a UINavigationBar inside a UIView?

Comment: Nope, It's in my view controller.  I want to access the navigation bar height from other views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the height of navigation bar by using following:

```
guard let rootVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController else { return }

let navigationBarHeight = rootVC.navigationBar.frame.height
```